# How to disable fsync on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is there a way to make `fsync` operations on Linux a no-op, ideally just for a single directory or mount point?

I am running some software which unfortunately I cannot modify which is doing excessive syncs.  I don't care about robustness in the event of a system crash (we will re-format if that happens and start over).

I have looked through the mount options for `xfs` and `ext4`, and couldn't find anything that looked like it would make `fsync` a no-op.

I have also considered using `tmpfs` instead of a regular filesystem, and using the available disk as additional swap.  I'm hoping for a neater option using a filesystem.

Comment: This might help: https://www.flamingspork.com/projects/libeatmydata/

Comment: for which os you are looking?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about your FS robuestness you can use the nobarrier mount option.

Comment: nobarrier is not recommended as a mount option. References include [suse](https://www.suse.com/c/xfs-nobarrier-option-is-now-more-than-deprecated/) and [Redhat[(https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/writebarrieronoff).